# Evaluation of Gaussian integral $\int^\infty_{-\infty}dx\;\exp(A(x-B)^2)$ with $A$, $B$ complex

Tags: integration, complex-numbers

Does
$$I = \int^\infty_{-\infty}dx \;\exp(re^{i\theta}(x-B)^2), \quad B \in \mathbb{C}$$
have a known standard result? I am hoping to use the result for exercises in the path integral formulation of quantum mechanics.

My approach is to substitute $x'=e^{i\phi}x$ , where $\phi = \dfrac{\pi-\theta}{2}$ (to obtain $-x^2$ in the exponent) and close contours at $\pm \infty$ to obtain
$$ I = e^{-i\phi}e^C\int^\infty_{-\infty}dx'\;\exp(-r(x'-\tilde{B})^2)$$
for some $\tilde{B}, C \in \mathbb{C}$ which result from completing the square
I then want to show $\dfrac{dI}{d\tilde{B}}=0$ to obtain a standard real integral and solve
$$I = e^{-i\phi}e^C\sqrt{\dfrac{\pi}{r}}
$$

However there are many steps I am unsure of (in particular there are 2 possible choices for $\phi$, only one of which seems to work so far), and I am hoping to compare my derivation to a known result. Could anyone point me to some derivation of this complex Gaussian integral ? (Or explain why this doesn't have a standard result)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLF43.png ??

Comment: Thank you! Sorry I should get used to using a program like Mathematica, completely slipped my mind

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/368186/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the standard result for $A>0$,
$$
I = \int^\infty_{-\infty}dx \;\exp(-A(x-B)^2)
= \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{A}}
$$
holds for all complex $B$ and all complex $A$ such that $\mathrm{Re}(A)>0$, with the condition that $\sqrt{\vphantom{A}\ \ \ }$ be understood as the principal branch of the square root, with the branch cut along the negative real axis. The result can be derived by

- (i) translating the integration variable by $\mathrm{Re}(B)$,
- (ii) translating the integration variable by $\mathrm{Im}(B)$, and then altering the integration path accordingly, and
- (iii) rotating the integration path by a unit complex factor of $e^{\pm \frac12 i \arg(A)}$,

which returns the integral to the $A>0$ case.

(As it happens, the integral also converges, to the same form, when $\mathrm{Re}(A)=0$, in which case it's a Fresnel integral, but the convergence conditions are very different.)